# Why isn't Vite hot reloading <template> in only some of the Vue components?

Tags: vite

When I change HTML in template tag in a Vue + Vite project, I'm getting an error:

> ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'ComponentName' before
> initialization

and

> [hmr] Failed to reload /src/views/ComponentName.vue. This could be due
> to syntax errors or importing non-existent modules. (see errors above)

This is true only for *some* components/views and only regards template, the script and style tags don't cause the erorr to happen. I cannot find any regularity in this, like it only affects a random number of components.